# Init a custom UITableViewCell with Reuseidentifier But Not Style

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView cell called ScheduleTableViewCell. It adds three subviews (labels) all programmatically (no NIB) in the initWithStyle. I can call in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method: `[[ScheduleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];` and everything works perfectly. I looked for a better to set the reuse identifier so that I do not have a bunch of labels and views which never get used (I only use the three I create), but could not find any. Is this the best way and should I not be concerned about the excess memory usage, or is there a better way to set the reuse identifier?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My code for creating my custom UITableViewCells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ScheduleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ScheduleTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }

    if (_grayedOut) {
        [[cell mainLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel1] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel2] setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    } else {
        [[cell mainLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel1] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [[cell subtitleLabel2] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    [[cell mainLabel] setText:[[[[[[[self appDelegate] user] days] objectAtIndex:_dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] desc]];
    [[cell subtitleLabel1] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Teacher: %@", [[[[[[[self appDelegate] user] days] objectAtIndex:_dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] teacher]]];
    [[cell subtitleLabel2] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@", [[[[[[[self appDelegate] user] days] objectAtIndex:_dayInt] periods] objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] roomLocation]]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You question is kind of unclear. Your UITableView should not dequeue more cells than it needs, which is provided in the dataSource method. Also, for the unused UILabels, you should look in to lazy initialization. This means that the UILabels will only be initialized when they are needed. Ex. when you set the text. In cellForRowAtIndexPath: you should instead call [tableView deqeueCellWithReuseIdentifier.

Comment: @Jonathan Basically I wanted to know if this was the best way to init my custom cells with identifiers and whether the extra labels' memory was significant.

Comment: Show us how you are creating cells in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath

Comment: For custom cells, all you need to do is call dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier. dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier will look for a cell in the queue to use and if one does not exist it will create it. initWithStyle is used when you want to use a predefined style. "To use a cell with a predefined style, initialize it using the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method or configure the cell with that style in Xcode." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: So in your case you can eliminate the initWithStyle and not worry about any extra memory.

Comment: @Jonathan but how will the table view know the cell's know the cells identifier, or does this not matter? And how are the initial cells initialized?

Comment: By registering the custom tableViewCell class using registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier Ex.[tableView registerClass:[MyCustomerTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; I highly recommend reading The Table View Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks for your help. Strange that after half an hour of googling how to do this that guide never came up. Very useful.

Comment: @Jonathan Interesting to note: the registerClass... actually calls `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault` to create the cells.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for letting me know. More than likely they are using lazy initialization so you still don't need to worry about wasted memory.